# Set image source to a value retrieved from a link href

Tags: javascript, html

How can I find the `href` attribute, then use it as the value of the image `src` attribute?

This what I have tried so far:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myAnchor").href;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
 var x = document.getElementById("myAnchor").href;
 document.getElementById("demo").setAtribute("src", x);
```

This should work assuming your <a> tag with the href has id myAnchor and your <img> has id demo.

Answer (score 0):

An `<img>` tag cannot have HTML inside of it. You're looking the [`HTMLImageElement.src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#Properties) property.

```js
var href = document.getElementById('myAnchor').href;
document.getElementById('demo').src = href;
```

```html
<a href="//placehold.it/100x100" id="myAnchor"><img id="demo"></a>
```